# Batch para repetir comando en consola Windows

Tags: batch

Necesito crear un batch para la consola de windows que me permita repetir un comando cada cierto tiempo.
Basicamente necesito repetir el comando gpupdate /force cada 3 minutos o, en todo caso, cuando finalize la tarea que se vuelva a repetir ese comando.
Encontre esta opcion en una pagina:
*4. Ejecuta varios comandos a la vez. Si necesitas ejecutar múltiples comandos, pero cada uno de ellos requiere mucho tiempo de ejecución, puedes adelantarte con la orden “cd C: && echo…”. Los comandos se ejecutarán en el orden en que los escribiste, comenzando desde la izquierda hasta la derecha de la consola. Los nuevos comandos no se ejecutan hasta que van terminando los anteriores.*
Puedo colocar el mismo comando para que lo repita, solo que no me indica como empezar el batch

Answer (score 1):

Quizá algo como esto te sirva:

```
cd\
c:
gpupdate /force /wait:180
exit
```